# How can I give my ImageView a percentage-based minimum width?

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, alignment

I have a list view, which I was populating with 75x75 px images, and some text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:minHeight="90dp"
        android:minWidth="90dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am now using an image server that can retrieve images of any size (I am requesting images that are 30% of the devices's width), so I would like to make my `ImageView` always take up 30% of the width of the list view. I tried using `android:layout_weight=".3"`, and `android:layout_weight=".7"` for the `ImageView` and `TextView`, but this caused two problems:

- Since my images are loaded asynchronously, the text moves to the right when the image is loaded, instead of already being in the correct place. This wasn't a problem before, since I could use `android:minHeight` and `android:minWidth`.
- The text and images are no longer nicely aligned (some are further to the left or right, and setting `gravity` and `layout_gravity` did not help.)

So, how can I make the `ImageView` take up 30% of the width (even before an image is set), and have all the images and text aligned properly?

Comment: You could avoid the first problem if you load the image view with a default bitmap before requesting an image from the server. You could create a needed bitmap with the right dimensions on the fly for that. As to your second problem is that caused while received images differ in width?

Comment: @greenapps Thanks, I'll try creating a bitmap placeholder. All images received will have the same width and height (the dimensions only change from device to device).